# Audio and Video Out of Sync in Preview

Tags: audio

When I import a screen recording from my computer and my corresponding VoiceOver to edit, they become out of sync as the video progresses. The audio is not longer than the video, they end at exactly the same time. Yes, I've changed the playback settings to Sync to Audio and Frame Dropping and neither fix the issue. I almost succeeded with changing the base to the frame rate and the frame rate itself, but it made the audio end too early. I haven't seen anybody else with this exact problem, so I decided to post here. If it helps, I'm gonna paste my computer specs here:

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)

Processor: 3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7

Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Running Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: since you seemed to check the "typical" issues, i recommend providing a blend file since we have no idea about any other settings you made so we can check it out on our own.